# Tensorflow Domain Adaptation How can i use two Bazel commands at the same time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

I am training neural networks with tensorflow. For that I am running the PixelDA models from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/domain_adaptation using the bazel run commands.

```
bazel run domain_adaptation/pixel_domain_adaptation:pixelda_train -- --dataset_dir $DSN_DATA_DIR --source_dataset mnist --target_dataset mnist_m
bazel run domain_adaptation/pixel_domain_adaptation:pixelda_eval -- --dataset_dir $DSN_DATA_DIR --source_dataset mnist --target_dataset mnist_m --target_split_name test
```

But I can either train a model OR evaluate. Not both at the same time. Even if I do both processes via ssh with another computer (so I excluded GPU issues)

When I have a running training process, and then start the eval process, the training terminates with this error message

```
Server terminated abruptly error code: 14, error message: '', log file: '/home/.../.cache/bazel/_bazel_.../c96d77bc006e939d39d6eba4227a082c/server/jvm.out'
```

How can I train and eval at the same time?

I tried to remove the log file and i tried to start the python scripts without bazel like `python domain_adaptation/pixel_domain_adaptation/pixelda_train.py -- --dataset_dir $DSN_DATA_DIR --source_dataset mnist --target_dataset mnist_m`. But then strange `ImportError: No module named research.domain_adaptation.pixel_domain_adaptation` occur. If i delete the "research" the same occurs.

- echo $PYTHONPATH is `:/home/.../models/research:/home/.../models/research/slim`
- Structure is `~/models/research/slim/...` and 
  `~/models/research/domain_adaptation/pixel_domain_adaptation/...`
- bazel version 0.11.1
- GPUs 2x Geforce GTX 1060 (2x6GB), 32GB RAM
- tensorflow 1.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this script in place of `bazel run`.

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/scripts/bazel-run.sh

This script releases the lock before executing the run target.

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as accepted so it's not [listed in the unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/bazel)